# total count and subset count inside a group by

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table with trips having a start date and end date. sometimes the trip is greater than 1 day most of the time it is not. Here is a sample of the first 10 records:

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| id   | start_date              | end_date                |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
| 7454 | 2013-09-01 01:01:00.000 | 2013-09-01 01:05:00.000 |
| 7457 | 2013-09-01 01:09:00.000 | 2013-09-01 01:12:00.000 |
| 7458 | 2013-09-01 02:01:00.000 | 2013-09-01 02:08:00.000 |
| 7459 | 2013-09-01 02:04:00.000 | 2013-09-01 02:23:00.000 |
| 7460 | 2013-09-01 02:04:00.000 | 2013-09-01 02:25:00.000 |
| 7461 | 2013-09-01 02:09:00.000 | 2013-09-01 02:12:00.000 |
| 7463 | 2013-09-01 02:19:00.000 | 2013-09-01 02:29:00.000 |
| 7465 | 2013-09-01 02:27:00.000 | 2013-09-01 02:29:00.000 |
| 7466 | 2013-09-01 04:06:00.000 | 2013-09-01 15:08:00.000 |
| 7467 | 2013-09-01 05:24:00.000 | 2013-09-01 05:37:00.000 |
+------+-------------------------+-------------------------+
```

I want to have a query that groups by start month - and gives the total trips in each month - and the num of trips greater than 1 day. and calculates the percentage of trips > day

Here is the query that does this for ALL trips in a single line:

```
SELECT 
count ([id]) as NumTrips
,(
    SELECT count ([id]) as NumTripsGreaterThanOneDay
    FROM [trip]
    where dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,[start_date]),0) < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,end_date),0)
) as 'NumTrips>Day'
,(
(
    SELECT count ([id]) as NumTripsGreaterThanOneDay
    FROM [trip]
    where dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,[start_date]),0) < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,end_date),0)
)*100.0 / count ([id])
) as 'percent>day'
FROM [trip]
```

And the result:

```
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| NumTrips | NumTrips>Day | percent>day    |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
| 669959   | 2099         | 0.313302754347 |
+----------+--------------+----------------+
```

I tried to do it with this code:

```
SELECT 
count ([id]) as NumTrips
,(
    SELECT count ([id]) as NumTripsGreaterThanOneDay
    FROM [trip]
    where dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,[start_date]),0) < dateadd(day,datediff(day,0,end_date),0)
) as 'NumTrips>Day'
,dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,[start_date]),0) as TripMonth
FROM [trip]
group by dateadd(month,datediff(month,0,[start_date]),0)
```

and got this result:

```
+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
| NumTrips | NumTrips>Day | TripMonth               |
+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
| 2102     | 2099         | 2013-08-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 25243    | 2099         | 2013-09-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 29105    | 2099         | 2013-10-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 24219    | 2099         | 2013-11-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 19894    | 2099         | 2013-12-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 24428    | 2099         | 2014-01-01 00:00:00.000 |
| 19024    | 2099         | 2014-02-01 00:00:00.000 |
+----------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

I see the problem is my subquery is not correlated inside the aggregate - but I can't figure out how to do this.  I think I probably need to do this with a partition - but I couldn't quite figure it out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to do it is using conditional aggregation:

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
CREATE TABLE trip 
(
    id int, 
    start_date datetime,
    end_date datetime
)

INSERT INTO trip VALUES
(7454, '2013-09-01 01:01:00.000', '2013-09-01 01:05:00.000'),
(7457, '2013-09-01 01:09:00.000', '2013-09-01 01:12:00.000'),
(7458, '2013-09-01 02:01:00.000', '2013-09-01 02:08:00.000'),
(7459, '2013-09-01 02:04:00.000', '2013-09-01 02:23:00.000'),
(7460, '2013-09-01 02:04:00.000', '2013-09-01 02:25:00.000'),
(7461, '2013-09-01 02:09:00.000', '2013-09-01 02:12:00.000'),
(7463, '2013-09-01 02:19:00.000', '2013-09-01 02:29:00.000'),
(7465, '2013-09-01 02:27:00.000', '2013-09-01 02:29:00.000'),
(7466, '2013-09-01 04:06:00.000', '2013-09-02 15:08:00.000'),
(7467, '2013-09-01 05:24:00.000', '2013-09-02 05:37:00.000')
```

The query:

```
SELECT  DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,[start_date]),0) As TripMonth,
        COUNT(id) As 'NumTrips',
        SUM
        (
            CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Start_Date, End_Date) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
        ) As 'NumTrips>Day'
FROM Trip
GROUP BY DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,[start_date]),0)
```

Results:

```
TripMonth               NumTrips    NumTrips>Day
01.09.2013 00:00:00     10          2
```

Comment: This is so much simpler than I thought!  Thank You.   I did add one extra line on the select clause to calculate the percentage: --- ,(SUM (CASE WHEN DATEDIFF(DAY, Start_Date, End_Date) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)*100.0)/ COUNT(*) as 'Percent>day'

Comment: Also - thanks for not downvoting me about creating the sample table.  I will do that in the future.

Comment: I usually downvote only the worst questions... yours isn't one of them.

Comment: I'm trying to learn SQL by doing exercises using kaggle data sets.  I will eventually get good enough at it to one day answer questions on here.  That day does seem like a fair ways of right now though...